# In 10.10, USB 3.0 PCI Express card recognized by lspci but not lsusb or dmesg. How to fix?

Tags: 10.10, usb

Asus N PC, runs 10.10 x86_64
The Asus N comes with 4 usb 2.0 ports, each labelled 2.0 on the case.

Attempting to add two usb 3.0 ports to be provided by a generic usb 3.0 pci express card installed in the pci expres slot.  The new card says usb 3.0 and has the blue ports.

The card is installed into the laptop unpowered, then the laptop is powered on and boots normally.  Nothing happens when a USB 3.0 flash drive is inserted into the usb 3.0 port.

uname -a

```
Linux drpaulbrewer-N90SV 2.6.35.8 #1 SMP Fri Jan 14 15:54:11 EST 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64
    Kernel modules: sis-agp

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fa000000-fdefffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [f4] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [70] Subsystem: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 [IDE] (rev 01) (prog-if 80 [Master])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 128
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at ffe0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: [58] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pata_sis

00:03.0 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 20
    Memory at f9fff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:03.1 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 21
    Memory at f9ffe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci_hcd

00:03.3 USB Controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 22
    Memory at f9ffd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11f5
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Memory at f9ffcc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: sis190
    Kernel modules: sis190

00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03) (prog-if 8f [Master SecP SecO PriP PriO])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1b27
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at c800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at c400 [size=4]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=8]
    I/O ports at bc00 [size=4]
    I/O ports at b800 [size=16]
    I/O ports at b400 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [58] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: sata_sis
    Kernel modules: sata_sis

00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fdf00000-fdffffff
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Device 0004
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [f4] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=06, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: fe000000-febfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f6000000-00000000f8ffffff
    Capabilities: [b0] Subsystem: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Device 0004
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [f4] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 17b3
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f9ff4000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G96 [GeForce GT 130M] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 2021
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at fa000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at fde80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidia-current, nouveau, nvidiafb

02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 1a3b:1067
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fdff0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [60] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=1 Masked-
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

03:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30)
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at febfe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
```

lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:1751 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. BT-253 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b071 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 2.0M UVC Webcam / CNF7129
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg

```
trying to post dmesg exceeded the stackexchange posting limit of 30K... but nothing there is usb 3.0
```

Comment: Could you paste the output of `sudo modprobe xhci-hcd`? And see if lsusb changes after doing that?

Comment: FATAL: Module xhci_hcd not found. No change (obviously, but checked anyway)

Comment: note the modprobe xhci-hcd uses dash, the error message uses underscore

Comment: That error would indicate that you don't have a USB 3.0 driver. It also looks like you're not using the standard maverick kernel. Could you let us know how you installed this? And paste the output of `dpkg -l linux-image* | grep ^ii` ?

Comment: The laptop is a Asus N90 and has a custom kernel because of  trouble with standard liveCDs and installs including 10.10 and 11.04 [recently tried].  The custom kernel has all the auto power management turned off, which allowed the computer to boot without messing around with kernel boot line parameters on a regular basis.  When I try booting with the most recent kernel update (it keeps downloading updated kernel binaries although pegged to the custom kernel in grub), it hangs. Booting with the "recovery" version shows the hang occurs at the PCI express hotplug driver. More later as time allows

Comment: Are you building this custom kernel yourself, or getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: Let me disambiguate. The asus n90 won't run any of the ubuntu linux-image-generic kernels without tweaking the params. I built the working kernel, one time, 8 or 9 months ago, following "compiling kernels the ubuntu way" or a similar article.  I did a lot of kernel compiles back in the 0.99 days, when linux came on floppies, but not so many under Ubuntu. Now there is more complexity to manage, plus keeping the package manager happy. If you want to make your answer that the xhci-hcd module is missing, and I need to use obtain a kernel that has this among the included modules, I can give points.

Comment: This leaves unresolved what is going on with the PCI express hotplug driver.  But that might be posted as another question if I can't make the problem go away, say, with a sledgehammer or a 11.04 alternate install CD and a bunch of "no" params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your kernel does not have the USB 3.0 host controller driver.

Since you're running a custom-built kernel, you'll need to add this to your current kernel build configuration.

The configuration parameter to enable this driver is `CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD`. You can enable this (within the `make menuconfig` dialogs), by enabling the 'xHCI HCD (USB 3.0) support' option.

This option can be found at: Device Drivers -> USB Support -> Support for Host-side USB' -> xHCI HCD (USB 3.0) support.